# Forming summarized dataframe from list of dictionary that have multiple keys indicates (sheet_name, column, index)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm writing a code that summarize 24 excel files into one excel with sheet.

I collect only one value from each of excel files and forming them into a dictionary list, a dictionary that have mulitple keys.

Here's this **dictionary structure**: **(Sheet_name, Columns, Index)**

```
('Explore Recommendation', 'Cosine Similarity', 'ModelD'):0.2079673923133115
('Explore Recommendation', 'Cosine Similarity', 'ModelC'):0.1836959487633592
('Explore Recommendation', 'Cosine Similarity', 'ModelB'):0.2965162341331296
('Explore Recommendation', 'Cosine Similarity', 'ModelA'):0.2305084031994787
('SimilarQuestions PR', 'Cosine Similarity', 'ModelD'):0.1302464678216582
('SimilarQuestions PR', 'Cosine Similarity', 'ModelC'):0.1286551634542706
('SimilarQuestions PR', 'Cosine Similarity', 'ModelB'):0.1166701796746994
('SimilarQuestions PR', 'Cosine Similarity', 'ModelA'):0.1298325593321064
('Explore Recommendation', 'Pearson Correlation', 'ModelD'):0.2036633790962548
('Explore Recommendation', 'Pearson Correlation', 'ModelA'):0.2235214281861879
('Explore Recommendation', 'Pearson Correlation', 'ModelB'):0.2968697694866649
('Explore Recommendation', 'Euclidean Distance', 'ModelB'):0.106538315118788
('Explore Recommendation', 'Euclidean Distance', 'ModelD'):0.0004444444444444445
('Explore Recommendation', 'Euclidean Distance', 'ModelC'):0.008107939296345092
('Explore Recommendation', 'Euclidean Distance', 'ModelA'):0.001904455179817499
('SimilarQuestions PR', 'Euclidean Distance', 'ModelA'):0.6065296911408916
('SimilarQuestions PR', 'Euclidean Distance', 'ModelB'):0.5113740238302591
('SimilarQuestions PR', 'Euclidean Distance', 'ModelD'):0.6055984158673821
('SimilarQuestions PR', 'Euclidean Distance', 'ModelC'):0.5793923674686116
('SimilarQuestions PR', 'Pearson Correlation', 'ModelB'):0.1432751419091906
('SimilarQuestions PR', 'Pearson Correlation', 'ModelA'):0.2158228930950112
('SimilarQuestions PR', 'Pearson Correlation', 'ModelD'):0.219417708709893
('SimilarQuestions PR', 'Pearson Correlation', 'ModelC'):0.20856317482422
```

I can also record them by using two different dictionary like this:

```
('Cosine Similarity', 'ModelD'):0.2079673923133115
('Cosine Similarity', 'ModelC'):0.1836959487633592
```

Here's my tries to forming dataframe from seperated dictionary:

```
model_list = [
    "ModelA",
    "ModelB",
    "ModelC",
    "ModelD",
]
matrix_type_list = [
    "Cosine Similarity",
    "Pearson Correlation",
    "Euclidean Distance",
]
pd.DataFrame(dataframe_dict1, columns=matrix_type_list, index=model_list)
```

But it seems that dataframe cannot iterate this dictionary:

```
       Cosine Similarity Pearson Correlation Euclidean Distance
ModelA               NaN                 NaN                NaN
ModelB               NaN                 NaN                NaN
ModelC               NaN                 NaN                NaN
ModelD               NaN                 NaN                NaN
```

Any suggestion would help. I can provide my pickle file that have this dictionary for testing.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a new dataframe from a dict, so the [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-from-dict) method wil come in handy. According to the docs, these are the function arguments:

> DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns', dtype=None, columns=None)

Where, data is a dict "Of the form {field : array-like} or {field : dict}".

This means, we can provide a dict where the columns of our dataframe come from the keys of the data dict, while the values come from an array-like structure (for example, a list) or from another dict (where keys are the index values and the dict values are the actual values in the dataframe). We'll use the second one, which looks something like this:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
...     "column1": {"indexA": 1, "indexB": 2},
...     "column2": {"indexA": 3, "indexB": 4},
... })
        column1  column2
indexA        1        3
indexB        2        4
```

Now let's go to your current dict. It is almost ready, we just need to take the last value from your tuple keys and use it as keys in our inner dict (just like "indexA" and "indexB"):

print(data)

```
>>> new_data = dict()
>>> for (sheet, column, index), value in data.items():
...     if (sheet, column) not in new_data:
...         new_data[(sheet, column)] = dict()
...     new_data[(sheet, column)][index] = value
```

Now, we are ready to go:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_data)
>>> df
       Explore Recommendation  ... SimilarQuestions PR
            Cosine Similarity  ... Pearson Correlation
ModelD               0.207967  ...            0.219418
ModelC               0.183696  ...            0.208563
ModelB               0.296516  ...            0.143275
ModelA               0.230508  ...            0.215823
```

Notice that your columns still have two levels, in case you need that to query your data.

Comment: It works as it should be. Thank you very much!
result image: https://imgur.com/wzJAVgV

Comment: Got it. I am new to post something else here. Did not see that mark last time I check this post. Sorry about that. :<